# ExecuteShell executing a powershell command does not find a function that works on powershell

Tags: c++, powershell

I'm executing a powershell script from c++ code using `ShellExecute` as bellow:

```
    bool ChangeWindowsUser(const CString& strOldUsername, const CString& strNewUsername)
    {
        CString powershellCommand;
        powershellCommand.Format(
        _T("if (Get-LocalUser -Name '%s' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) { \n")
        _T("    #Rename the user \n")
        _T("    Rename-LocalUser -Name '%s' -NewName '%s' \n")
        _T("} else { \n")
        _T("    exit 1; \n") // Devuelve código de error (oldUsername no existe)
        _T("} \n"),
        strOldUsername, strOldUsername, strOldUsername, strNewUsername, strOldUsername);
    
        ShellExecute(NULL, _T("runas"), _T("C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"), powershellCommand, NULL, SW_SHOW); 
    }
```

And I get the following error:

> Get-LocalUser : The term 'Get-LocalUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
> program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
> At line:4 char:5

I have tried adding:

- Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
- Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts

But it didn't work

If I execute the same powershell script directly in powershell it works.

¿Could this directly be done with c++ code?

Comment: Read about the `-Command` option in the documentation.

Comment: @molbdnilo is a c++ problem not a powershell problem

Comment: Open your terminal and try both `powershell 'echo "hi"'` and `powershell -Command 'echo "hi"'`.

Comment: @molbdnilo as I wrote in the post, if I execute the same command directly from powershell it works fine

Comment: Entering a command at the powershell prompt is not the same as passing it as an argument to the powershell executable. If you enter `command` at the prompt, the equivalent is `powershell.exe -Command command`.